# Mongoose find() returning array empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following product model:

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
let produtoSchema = new Schema(
    {
        descricao: { type: String, required: true },
        gateways: [ { type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gateway' } ]
    }
);

mongoose.model('Produto', produtoSchema);
```

The the following collection:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.produtos.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55fef1a3d7c6912033f2da72"),
    "descricao" : "Product description",
    "gateways" : [
        ObjectId("55fee8a97cb7db7740acb322")
    ]
}
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

So, I'm trying to use Mongoose to fetch a specific product, but 'gateway' array is empty :

```
let Produto       = mongoose.model('Produto');
Produto.find(
{
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("55fef1a3d7c6912033f2da72")

}, function(err, result) 
{
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(result);
});
```

And the result is :

```
[ { _id: 55fef1a3d7c6912033f2da72,
    descricao: 'Product description',
    gateways: [] } ]
```

A also tried, but with the same result:

```
Produto
.find( { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("55fef1a3d7c6912033f2da72") })
.populate('gateways')
.exec(function(err, result) 
{
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `_id: "55fef1a3d7c6912033f2da72"`

Comment: Same result. I'm fetching the document, the only problem is that gateway[ ] array is empty instead of gateway [ ObjectId("55fee8a97cb7db7740acb322") ]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

I've changed:

```
gateways: [ { type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gateway' } ]
```

by

```
gateways: [ { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Gateway' } ]
```

What's the difference between them ?